# greuests alternative - python

Tags: python, concurrency, compilation

I am developing a program that downloads multiple pages, and I used grequests to minimize the download time and also because it supports requests session since the program requires a login. grequests is based on gevent which gave me a hard time when compiling the program (py2exe, bbfreeze). Is there any alternative that can use requests sessions ? Or are there any tips on compiling a program with gevent ?

**I can't use pyinstaller**: I have to use esky which allows updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, there are plenty of alternatives. There's absolutely no reason you have to use `gevent`—or greenlets at all—to download multiple pages.

If you're trying to handle thousands of connections, that's one thing, but normally a parallel downloader only wants 4-16 simultaneous connections, and any modern OS can run 4-16 threads just fine. Here's an example using Python 3.2+. If you're using 2.x or 3.1, download the [`futures`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures) backport from PyPI—it's pure Python, so you should have no trouble building and packaging it.

```
import concurrent.futures
import requests

def get_url(url, other, args):
    # your existing requests-based code here

urls = [your, list, of, page, urls, here]

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
    pool.map(get_url, urls)
```

If you have some simple post-processing to do after each of the downloads on the main thread, the [example](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) in the docs shows how to do exactly that.

If you've heard that "threads are bad in Python because of the GIL", you've heard wrong. Threads *that do CPU-bound work in Python* are bad because of the GIL. Threads that do I/O-bound work, like downloading a web page, are perfectly fine. And that's *exactly the same restriction as when using greenlets*, like your existing `grequests` code, which works.

---

As I said, this isn't the only alternative. For example, `curl` (with any of its various Python bindings) is a pain to get the hang of in the first place compared to `requests`—but once you do, having it multiplex multiple downloads for you isn't much harder than doing one at a time. But threading is the *easiest* alternative, especially if you've already written code around greenlets.

---

* In 2.x and 3.1, it *can* be a problem to have a single thread doing significant CPU work while background threads are doing I/O. In 3.2+, it works the way it should.